# How to transfer Brokerage Account from USA to Canada?

Tags: canada, brokerage

I am a new permanent resident in Canada (Venezuelan citizen).

Since several years ago I have brokerage accounts in the US (in OptionsExpress).

OptionsExpress doesn't serve Canadian residents, so I am forced to move my account to Canada. I want to do it anyways to register some RRSP and TSFA accounts.

I am trying to figure out if such a account transfer between US and Canadian institution is possible and if it makes sense (it doesn't take forever, they do not convert currencies, etc). The "simple" option is to liquidate everything and bring in the money but that has taxes and fees implications.

Comment: I have transferred share across countries before, but I don't remember how (basically the bank did it all). I know this is little help for you, but at least you know it's possible.

Comment: I can say that both Qtrade and Questrade have told me they can do it. Timing is supposed to be between 5 and 20 business days (ouch). I guess I'll to try.